Getting zeros for all metrics during LLM RAG Evaluation
I am doing evaluation on huggingface datasets like hotpot-qa. But the results are like this:
'precision_at_2/mean': 0.0, 'recall_at_2/mean': 0.0, 'ndcg_at_2/mean':0.0 .........
I don't know why i am getting zeros.Here is my dataframe. The results are predictions from a langchain llm RAG:

results = mlflow.evaluate( 
    data=eval_data,
        model_type="retriever",
        evaluators="default",
        predictions="results",
        targets="answer",
        extra_metrics=[
            mlflow.metrics.ndcg_at_k(2),
            mlflow.metrics.recall_at_k(2),
            mlflow.metrics.precision_at_k(2),
            mlflow.metrics.latency()],
        evaluator_config={
            "col_mapping": {
                "inputs": "question",
                "context": "context",
                "targets": "answer",
            }
        },)

Is there any issue with the structure of columns "answer" and "results"?
Here is the notebook
https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1CZ27v9Uf_QvfgtP9UDYWas3yMMpIfZ5y?usp=sharing
How can I get the values for metrics correctly? Please help
